# Is there any possibility to sort by visible text, not link text?

Tags: bootstrap-table

I'm using Bootstrap Table to sort some columns. One column has an article title that links to the article itself. I obviously want to be able to sort by title, but it's sorting by the content of the cell as seen in the source code (the link and the title) rather than the visible text (the title.)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-sortable">
  <thead>
    <th data-sortable="true">Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">Posted</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-sortable="true"><a href="link&ID=1">Article C</a></td>
      <td data-sortable="true">This is description 1</td>
      <td data-sortable="true">9/26/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td data-sortable="true"><a href="link&ID=3">Article A</a></td>
      <td data-sortable="true">This is description 2</td>
      <td data-sortable="true">4/27/2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td data-sortable="true"><a href="link&ID=2">Article B</a></td>
      <td data-sortable="true">This is description 3</td>
      <td data-sortable="true">8/26/2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

In the example it loads as C, A, B. After hitting the sort button I'd expect it to be A, B, C but it sorts as C, B, A (corresponding to 1, 2, 3 in the links.)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/melisunde/edkz6cv2/11/

Is there a way to have Bootstrap Table ignore the link? This doesn't appear to be addressed in the site's examples. Thanks!